# Alternative of ctx.updateSubTypes Telgraf 4

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf, telegraf.js

That end point was removed with new version of telgraf
[https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/releases/tag/v4.0.0#:~:text=ctx.updateSubTypes](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/releases/tag/v4.0.0#:%7E:text=ctx.updateSubTypes)

How we can detect the message type with new API

[image]

this is the old ctx retrun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative usage to `ctx.updatesubtypes` AKA getting message type in **telegraf 3**.

```js
bot.use((ctx, next) => {
    console.log(`Message Type is: ${getMessageType(ctx.message)}`); 
    // Message Type is: STICKER or Message Type is: TEXT
});
```

```js
const getMessageType = (message) => {
    var keys = Object.keys(message);
    var messageType = keys.pop();
    console.log(messageType);
    return messageType.toUpperCase();
};
```

source is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052712/10694425

Comment: good, but not always the last **key** is **text** : `keys.pop()`

Answer (score 0):

A `good` alternative to using **ctx.updatesubtypes** in 4.6.0 is:

```
bot.use((ctx, next) => {
  let message_type = "";
  let keys = Object.keys(ctx.message);
  
  if (keys.includes("text")) {
    message_type = "text";
  } else if (keys.includes("sticker")) {
    message_type = "sticker";
  } else if (keys.includes("photo")) {
    message_type = "photo";
  }
  console.log(`Message Type is: ${message_type}`);
  next();
});
```