# How can I retrieve the last nested property?

Tags: jquery, object

Is there an easy way with js/jquery to get the last entry of the periods in the object below without iterating? Ie accessing

```
"19": {
 "userId": "000011"
}
```

From

```
{
    "clients": {
        "periods": {
            "1": {
                "userId": "000015"
            },
            "19": {
                "userId": "000011"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16590272/1264804) seems to meet your requirements. Note that object properties are unordered in JavaScript, so what's last may change. You may want to restructure to make the value of `periods` an array of objects, which would then have a fixed order.