# JQGrid getGridParam not returning ID of data item

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a grid that is using local data generated from an external ajax request (by external I mean not using the inbuilt ajax of jqgrid)

the data from the ajax request is passed into the grid as local data and the grid is set to loadonce.

```
window.grid = $(window.tableName).jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: DataFromResponse,
            height: "auto",
            autowidth: true,
            hidegrid: false,
            ignoreCase: true,
            loadonce: true,
            pager: window.pagerName,
            rowNum: 10,
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption: '',
            colNames :[cols],
            colmodel :[]{cols},
            gridComplete: function() {
                CreateButtons();
            });
```

As you can see the grid is basic at this stage, however we need to add some buttons within a column named 'buttons' we use the **CreateButtons** method to do this.

The

```
function CreateButtons(){
   var grid = $(window.tableName);
   var data = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
   $.each(data, function(index, item){
      var cl = item._id_;
      alert(cl);
   });    
}
```

the alert of this function should give me the id of the row as set by the grid but it is not working any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `_id_` exist in internal `data` parameter only if the data loaded from remote source (`datatype` is `"json"` of `"xml"`) and the option `loadonce: true` was used. If one load the data locally (one uses `datatype: "local"`) then `_id_` is not exist.

If you correctly fill the grid the data specified by `data` parameter (`DataFromResponse` in your case) is array of items which contains `id` property together with the other properties used to fill the column data. One other option is specifying of `key: true` for some column. In the case the `id` for the row will be get from the column.

If you don't specified and `id` information (which is very bad) and you need to access all local data inclusive the ids generated by jqGrid you need get two jqGrid options: `_index` and `data`. The object `_index` contains as properties all ids of the grid. The value of the id property is integer index in `data` array which corresponds the id. So you can use `for-in` loop to enumerate all ids of the grid (you need enumerate properties of `_index`). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417757/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373813/315935) for details.

You wrote additionally that you created buttons in a column of the grid inside of `gridComplete`. The approach seems me not good. It's better to use custom formatter instead together with `gridview: true` option (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935)). Moreover I don't recommend you to use `gridComplete` at all. It's better to use `loadComplete`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935) for details.

Comment: i am editing a grid from using non-local data to using local data, I had set key = true but had lost the id for the reasons you said above. I replaced with the index of the column that had been set as the key and all worked thank you