# jqGrid: function $("#gridView").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data") return null?

Tags: jqgrid

I had a problem with jqGrid
When i use:

```
$("#gridView").jqGrid({
    url:"grid.php",
    colModel:[
            { name: 'id', index:'id'},          
    ],
    datatype: "json",
    mtype:"post",

    height:350,
    rownumbers:true,
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel : 'adjacency',
    ExpandColumn : 'id',
    ExpandColClick: true 
    ....

$("#gridView").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data") return array
```

---

```
$("#gridView").jqGrid({
    url:"grid.php",
    colModel:[
            { name: 'id', index:'id'},          
    ],
    datatype: "json",
    mtype:"post",
    pager:"#pager",
    rowNum:50,
    rowList:[10,50,100,500,1000],
    viewrecords:true,

    height:350,
    rownumbers:true,
    ....

$("#gridView").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data") return null ??
```

I've read article here [JQGrid getGridParam not returning ID of data item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715248/jqgrid-getgridparam-not-returning-id-of-data-item)

But I cannot set loadonce:true because of my dynamic data for each click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `loadonce: true` in case of `treeGrid: true`. jqGrid fills internal parameters `data` and `_index` for treegrid automatically (see [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L1551-L1555) of the code).

I suppose that you get `null` as the value of `data` parameter because you try to access `data` **before** the data will be loaded from the server. Try to use `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` inside of `loadComplete` callback. The callback will be called *after* filling of `data`.

Comment: Thank Oleg,
_**Try to use $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data") inside of loadComplete callback**_ ----

but I need to getGridParam in another function (ex: get data to for a form)

Comment: @LamLe: I mean that one possible reason of `null` as the value of `data` is that you try to get `data` **before** the data will be filled from the server. The code which you included looks like you included `$("#gridView").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` **directly after** `$("#gridView").jqGrid({...});` which creates the grid. The *filling* of the grid from `url:"grid.php"` works asynchronously. So only *after* the `data` are filled you can get it. I recommend you to try to include `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` inside of `loadComplete` callback to verify that `data` will do filled.

Comment: I'm sorry, my post is not match with my real code.---
After load complete, I made a "edit(row id)" button on each row. When I clicked "edit" button, **$("#gridView").get("getGridParam", "data")** return **[]** as I mentioned. I was so confused because my grid had already loaded, it had data to show on screen.

Comment: @LamLe: `$("#gridView").get(..)` is wrong. One should use `$("#gridView").jqGrid(...)`. If I understand you correctly you'v found already the problem and fixed the code.