# Move key in object of object up (swap indexes)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, key

I'm working with an object of objects. I need to keep it as an object because I'm work with an API that requires me to keep it that way (that part is not debatable).

This is an example schema of my object:

```
const obj = {
  1: { name: 'Initial Step 1', stepNumber: 1 },
  2: { name: 'Initial Step 2', stepNumber: 2 },
  3: { name: 'Initial Step 3', stepNumber: 3 },
}
```

I need to implemented a `moveUp` function that will take the `stepNumber` and `obj` as the first and second parameters respectively.

This `moveUp` function basically needs to swap one inner object with the object above it. Eg. `moveUp(2, obj)` should change the `obj` as follows:

```
{
  1: { name: 'Initial Step 2', stepNumber: 1 },
  2: { name: 'Initial Step 1', stepNumber: 2 },
  3: { name: 'Initial Step 3', stepNumber: 3 },
}
```

The `stepNumber` will never be equal to `1`, thanks to the interface I've built.

How should I implement my `moveUp` function?

I basically need this:

```
export const moveUp = (stepNumber, obj) => {
    // I need help here
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Barry if you're relying on the order here, you're going to run into an issue. Object keys don't keep a consistent order [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959817/changing-the-order-of-the-object-keys) is some discussion on it.

Comment: Should your step number for 'Initial Step 2' be set to 2?

Comment: @Callam What is this snippet supposed to do/show? O.o The relevant function is empty...

Comment: @espresso_coffee The input and output I've pointed out is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Beau I'm not relying on order, I'm creating it.

Comment: @Andreas note taken :P

Comment: @Beau: They do as of ES2015+, but legacy operations aren't required to respect it; [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and adjust `stepNumber`.

```js
function moveUp(object, key) {
    [object[key], object[key - 1]] = [object[key - 1], object[key]];
    object[key].stepNumber++;
    object[key - 1].stepNumber--;
}

var object = { 1: { name: 'Initial Step 1', stepNumber: 1 }, 2: { name: 'Initial Step 2', stepNumber: 2 }, 3: { name: 'Initial Step 3', stepNumber: 3 } };

moveUp(object, 2);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let _ = require('lodash');
obj = {
    1: { name: 'Initial Step 1', stepNumber: 1 },
    2: { name: 'Initial Step 2', stepNumber: 2 },
    3: { name: 'Initial Step 3', stepNumber: 3 },
  }

function moveUp(sn, objToUp){
    console.log(objToUp);
    let key =  _.findKey(obj,{stepNumber: sn} );
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let keyIndex = _.indexOf(keys, key);
    if(keyIndex > 0){
        let tmp = obj[keys[keyIndex-1]];
        obj[keys[keyIndex-1]] = objToUp;
        obj[keys[keyIndex]] = tmp;
    }
    console.log(obj);
}
moveUp(2, obj['2']);
```