# show the results order in angular controller same as it was sent from spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, javascript-objects

I'm returning a Map from java spring controller to the angularjs controller.
The Map in the java controller contains the following keys in the order `11,12,14,15,18,22,25,27,34,29` mapped to a value which i'm sending to the js controller. Issue is when i'm iterating and showing the response on the webpage, it is showing result in the sorted manner like `11,12,14,15,18,22,25,27,29,34`.
How to prevent this and show in the order i have sent from the java controller `(i.e.,11,12,14,15,18,22,25,27,34,29)` (Please note the difference is in last two values 34,29)

js code:

```
angular.forEach($scope.myResponse, function (value, key) {
    //here the results i get are in the order 11,12,14,15,18,22,25,27,29,34.
    //how to show the results as it was sent from java spring controller 11,12,14,15,18,22,25,27,34,29
});
```

Comment: Can you check and confirm in network tab of developer tools, if you are receiving it in the order you need?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that Angular is doing any kind of sorting on your behalf without your tacit permission.  What is the type of map you're getting back - `HashMap`?  `TreeMap`?

Comment: Its a LinkedHashMap@Makoto

Answer (score 0):

Chrome sorts propery names if they can be parsed as integers.

From the Docs:

> ### Wrong order in Object properties interation
>
> ECMA-262 does not specify enumeration order. The de facto standard is to match
>   insertion order, which V8 also does, but with one exception:
>
> V8 gives no guarantees on the enumeration order for array indices (i.e., a property
>   name that can be parsed as a 32-bit unsigned integer).
>
> Remembering the insertion order for array indices would incur significant memory
>   overhead.
>
> [— Chromium issue #164](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164)

To guarantee the order, send the data as an array of key/value pairs.

See also:

- [Changing the order of the Object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6959924/5535245)
- [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key/31102605#31102605)
- [ES6 Specification 9.1.12 - OwnPropertyKeys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys)
- [ES Discuss Property ordering of `getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/property-ordering-of-enumerate-getownpropertynames)