# Javascript / JQuery - How do I find the size of this array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this code to iterate through an array of objects:

```
for (vehicleIndex in scenes[sceneID].vehicles) {
  vehicleID = scenes[sceneID].vehicles[vehicleIndex];
  ...
}
```

but I need to know how to determine the number of items being iterated through so that on the final item, I can execute a particular function. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example in ES5:

```
Object.keys( scenes[sceneID].vehicles ).forEach(function( vehicle, index, arr ) {
    if( index === arr.length - 1 ) {
        // do something on last entry
    }
});
```

Even tho, "last" just means the last element which was looped over. Since there is specific order within a Javascript object (they are infact unordered). However, we could sort the object key names manually by just chaining a `.sort()` before the `.forEach()`

Comment: The "default sorting" is also implementation specific as objects are bags of un-ordered keys (hence not associative arrays)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arraySize = scenes[sceneID].vehicles.length;
var i;
var currentItem;
for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
  currentItem = scenes[sceneID].vehicles[i];
  if (i == arraySize - 1) {
    // do something special
  } else {
     // do something not so special ;-)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scenes[sceneID].vehicles should have a length property.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to find the length:

```
scenes[sceneID].vehicles.length
```

`length` is a built-in property in arrays. However, if you want to check for the last item, you have to check

```
scenes[sceneID].vehicles.length - 1
```

as arrays are zero-indexed.

Also, you should not use `for...in` to loop on arrays - if someone extends `Array.prototype` (or worse, `Object.prototype`), then you will not be happy. Use a normal `for` loop (which also allows you to use the final item easily):

```
var len = scenes[sceneID].vehicles.length;
for (var vehicleIndex = 0; vehicleIndex < len; vehicleIndex++) {
  vehicleID = scenes[sceneID].vehicles[vehicleIndex];
  //...
}
//Do something with the final item here
//Similar to this: itemFunc(vehicleID);
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) for more details.

Comment: for...in can be used safely if you have an if statement to check if the property belongs to the object in question or it was inherited (.hasOwnProperty())

Comment: @jbabey True. However, the order of iteration is undefined, and the final item cannot be reliably accessed after the loop if you do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-for-in-loop-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
for (vehicleIndex in scenes[sceneID].vehicles) {
  vehicleID = scenes[sceneID].vehicles[vehicleIndex];
  ...
}
doSomethingWithLastItem(vehicleId);
```

Because JS does not have block scope, by the time your loop finished `vehicleId` will be the last item's id.

In generic terms you can get the size of an array by accessing the `.length` property. You can also get the size of an object using `Object.keys(obj).length`.