# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wikipedia-api

I'm doing a project with the wikipedia media API. I'm querying the API using Jquery. The following request works when checking the developper console in Chrome as seen in this codepen http://codepen.io/jowze/pen/NNZNKY/?editors=1010

```
$.ajax({
 url:'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
  data: { action : 'query', generator: 'search', gsrnamespace : '0', gsrlimit : '10', prop : 'extracts', pilimit: 'max',
 exintro: '', explaintext: '', exsentences: '1' , exlimit: 'max' , gsrsearch: 'Richard Feynman', format: 'json'},
  dataType: 'jsonp',

  success: function (x) {
  var result = x.query.pages;  
    for (var i in result) {
    var item = result[i].pageid;
  console.log(item);

    }
  }
});
```

This code works when looping through the result with a for...in loop. When writing the same code trying to access the result variable like below, the console prints an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageid' of undefined`

```
 success: function (x) {
  var result = x.query.pages;  
    var item = result[0].pageid;
  console.log(item);

  }
});
```

Any idea why this is happening? Why is it impossible to access each key of the JSON object via `result[0]`, `result[1]`,... ,`result[n]`?

Comment: The keys seem to strings (results is a dictionary). Could you add the output of `console.log(result)`?

Comment: You are not able to access them via `index` because `x.query.pages` returns you a JSON object and not of the type `Array`. Only `Array` elements can be accessed by `index`.

Comment: typeof(x.query.pages) gives an object and not an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put some console logs as mentioned in the below code and you will understand why are you facing this error.

```
    $.ajax({
    url:'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    data: { action : 'query', generator: 'search', gsrnamespace : '0', gsrlimit : '10', prop : 'extracts', pilimit: 'max', exintro: '', explaintext: '', exsentences: '1' , exlimit: 'max' , gsrsearch: 'Richard Feynman', format: 'json'},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (x) {
        var result = x.query.pages;
        console.log("== What is the type of result : " + typeof(result)); //Object
        console.log("Complete Result : " + JSON.stringify(result));
        for (var i in result) {
            console.log("Property type for object result :" + typeof(i)); //String
            var item = result[i].pageid;
            var title = result[i].title;
            var extract = result[i].extract;
        }
    }
 });
```

So, What you are trying to do here is to access the non-numeric object properties by index, which is not possible. If you want to do it, then you can learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866275/access-non-numeric-object-properties-by-index).

Answer (score 0):

The keys of your result object are very large integers (not 0, 1, 2). `results` is not an array, it's a JS object. Hence indices don't start with 0.

```
for (var i in result)
```

.. iterates over every key in the object and hence `result[i]` works. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for reference.

Comment: what exactly you mean by "keys of your result object are very large integers (not 0, 1, 2)"?

Comment: Have a look at the results object. The keys / properties are six digit numbers. Probably "properties" is a better word here

Answer (score 0):

I think you can log what it is result like this:

```
success: function (x) {
  var result = x.query.pages;  
      var item = result[0].pageid;
      console.log(result,result[0]);
  }
});
```

**result[0]** mustn't has a key named **foo** if it's a project

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you tried to do `result[0]` which reads the first element of an array called `result`. Since `results` is an object, thus `result[0]` means you are trying to access `result.0` which in this case does not always exist.

With `result[0].pageid` you are trying access `result.0.pageid` which obviously won't exist if `result.0` doesn't exist. Therefore, you will get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageid' of undefined".