# How to access property of js object

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the response code

```
echo json_encode( array('success' => $stat,'msg'=>$file));
```

return from the server response

```
Object {success: "success", msg: "2017_nissan_gtr-2560x14409.jpg"}
```

Comment: You only have two properties in a single object, you've got nothing to iterate through

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access non-numeric Object properties by index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866275/access-non-numeric-object-properties-by-index)

Comment: U need to iterate through the properties for the object ??

Comment: Your question was misleads to give your answer so please use proper words in your question so we can give answer in right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var response = {success: "success", msg: "2017_nissan_gtr-2560x14409.jpg"}
var success = response.success;
var msg = response.msg;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate object by below code.

```
var obj= {success: "success", msg: "2017_nissan_gtr-2560x14409.jpg"}
for(var i in obj)
{
 alert(i+" :: "+ obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: You want to iterate all property of object or access predefined property of object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()`:

```js
var respObj = {
  success: "success",
  msg: "2017_nissan_gtr-2560x14409.jpg"
}
Object.keys(respObj).forEach(function(k) {
   console.log('key::::>', k,' value::::> ', respObj[k]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

U can iterate through the object properties using the following code..

```
 $.each(obj, function (key, value) { });
```