# how can I bind an object values to the dynamically added input field using vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object in an array which properties and values are dynamically added like this

```
  dataArray: [
    {
      first_name: "john",
      last_name: "doe",
      age: "45"
    }
  ]
```

I want to create input field corresponding to the object property so I do this

```
<input v-for="(item,index) in dataArray[0]" :key="index" v-model="item[index]"></input>
```

Input fields are created but how can I bind the value with the object property,
i try to do with (v-model="item[index]") but its not working.

Comment: If you change `v-model="item"` it will print your values in the input fields, but I don't think those will be reactive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a data `item[index]`, try with:

```
v-model="dataArray[0][index]"
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried with the wrong directive, Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, item is an object (dataArray[0]). Object properties don't have an index, so it's not possible to do what you're trying. item[index] is looking for a property key named "0", "1" and "2", which don't exist.

If all your objects in dataArray have different properties, you should create an array of the object keys using Object.keys() and use those to get all the property values. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866275/access-non-numeric-object-properties-by-index) for examples).

Comment: Not true. You can use interchangably `item.index` as well as `item[index]`. In the question above it works `dataArray[0][index]`, but not as `item[index]` for some reason and I am trying to figure it as I am curious.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `index` in this case as the `item` already represents the value:

```
<input v-for="(item,index) in dataArray[0]" :key="index" v-model="item"></input>
```

However the issue with this approach is that your model won't be reactive. One way around it is to do it this way.

1. Change your html to

   `<input v-for="(item,index) in dataArray[0]" :key="index" @keyup="change(index, $event.target.value)"></input>`
2. Add change method to your Vue instance code:

   `methods: {
       change(index, val) {
         this.dataArray[0][index] = val;
         console.log(index + ': ' + val);
       }
   }`

I am actually would be curious to see what another solution for this might be.