# Accessing Random Property of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have a huge object that contains the entire ESV Bible. I am trying to get a random book of the Bible whenever I press a button. Here is a small sample of the object.

```
var esvObject = {

 "Genesis": {

    "1": {}
    "2": {}
    "3": {}

   },
 "Exodus": {

    "1": {}
    "2": {}
    "3": {}

   }

}
```

Here is the code that I am using to get a random book.

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 66);

var randBook = esvObject[randNum];

var output = randBook;
```

I would expect this to work, but the output I always get is "undefined," where as I would like the output to be "Genesis" or "Exodus" etc. Getting the random number works, but if

```
randNum = 1
```

then

```
randBook = esvObject[1]
```

the output returns as "undefined" and I don't know why.

Comment: What do you expect `esvObject[1]` to return? `esvObject` doesn’t contain a key `1`, does it?

Comment: I would expect it to return "Exodus." In the object 0 is "Genesis," and 1 is "Exodus."

Comment: And the OP disappears....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick random property from a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2532218/90527)

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason you get undefined is that your object is of the structure:

```
let esvObject = {
   bookName: {
      1 : {}
   }
}
```

Using bracket `[]` notation on a javascript object finds the matching key for the name and returns it's value. In your top level object (the one with `bookNames` for keys), you have to use a valid book name like `Genesis`. To do so, leverage the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function of javascript to get an array of all the keys in your object.

You can then use `[]` notation, which has a different semantic on arrays.

```
let books = Object.keys(esvObject); // ["Genesis", "Exodus", ...]
let randomKey = books[randNum] // this is an array, so index access works
let book = esvObject[randomKey]  // matches on the bookname
```

And to tie it all together, `esvObject["Genesis"][1]` would have been valid because the object stored as "Genesis" has a property `1`

Answer (score 0):

You are generating random number. And then trying to pick property using that number.

But you object has properties Genesis and Exodus not 1 or 20 etc.
What you need to do is `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(esvObject)`
that will give you array of the property names. In this case ['Genesis', 'Exodus'] and then you need to pick random element from that array

Answer (score 0):

It would not work because it does not know that the first book is named "Genesis".
To be able to use numbers from the random function you will need to use array from the keys of the object

```
var keys = esvObject.keys( obj );
randBookKey = keys[randNum]
randBook = esvObject[randBookKey]
```

Answer (score 0):

`esvObject` (as you show it) does not have any integer keys. So you need to select a random (existing) key instead:

```
esvObject[Object.keys(esvObjects)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 66)]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I have tried that before, and the result was [object Object]

Comment: @Caleb Well, this will return an object. If you covert it to a string you'll get `[object Object]`. That shouldn’t come in surprising. If you just want the name of the book only use `Object.keys(esvObjects)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 66)]`

Comment: The name of the book will output as a string though right? So if I assign a variable to     `esvObject[Object.keys(esvObjects)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 66)]]`, it will output as a string, right?

Comment: No, `Object.keys(esvObjects)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 66)]` gives you a string. One of the keys of your objects, i.e. a name of a book. If you use that string to access `esvObject`, you’ll get whatever is assigned to this property. In your case, `{

    "1": {}
    "2": {}
    "3": {}

   }` (note that you missed commas)

Comment: I did this `randBook = esvObject[Object.keys(esvObject)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 66)]]` and the output was [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing accessing an array with accessing an object.

An array:

```
arr = ["genesis", "exodus"]
```

is accessed like this:

```
arr[0] // genesis
```

An object:

```
obj = { "genesis" : "foo", "exodus" : "bar"}
```

is accessed like this:

```
obj["genesis"] // foo
```

To achieve what you want to do, see [Access non-numeric Object properties by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866275/access-non-numeric-object-properties-by-index)