# Altair - use nth column as input variable in graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, altair

I would like to refer to the **nth** column of a dataframe and use this as input for drawing a graph using altair. 
 The code looks like this:

```
#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05', '2020-04-06','2020-04-03', '2020-04-04','2020-04-05','2020-04-06'],
                    'ID': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],'bar': [np.nan,8,np.nan,np.nan, np.nan, 8,np.nan,np.nan],
                    'line': [8,np.nan,10,8, 4, 5,6,7] })

#define columns to be used
bb = df.columns[2]
ll = df.columns[3]

#make graph
bars = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(color="grey", size=5).encode(
         alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), alt.Y(bb))

lines = (alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True,size=2)
     .transform_filter('isValid(datum.line)')
     .encode(alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), y='line:Q'))

alt.layer(bars + lines,width=350,height=150).facet(facet=alt.Facet('ID:N'),
    ).resolve_axis(y='independent',x='independent')
```

I managed for the "bars" part of the graph. But I am not sure how to do this inside
the `transform_filter` function. Instead of specifying the column name "line" I would like to use "ll" or the 3rd column of the dataframe.  
 Is there a way to do this? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datum` is referencing a javascript object, and [I don't believe there is any way to access javascript object properties (like `line`) by index rather than property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866275/access-non-numeric-object-properties-by-index). However you could construct the string using Python f-strings which allows you to substitute in the variable value where you need it in the string:

```
.transform_filter(f'isValid(datum.{ll})')
```

There is also an `expr` module in Altair ([second example here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/calculate.html#calculate-transform)), but I can't think of a way to use that which is easier than the above.