# EmberJS Set Multiple Properties At Once

Tags: ember.js

I am setting lots of properties with a series of set calls e.g.

```
this.set('prop1', value1);
this.set('prop2', value2);
.......
```

Is there a way to do this in one call (similar to when I create an object)? E.g.

```
this.setMultiple({prop1: value1, prop2: value2});
```

I still don't fully grok Ember's inheritance model. Maybe something along the lines of `reopen`?

Comment: Hm, if I were writing this API, I'd make `set` polymorphic, and accept either a key and a value, or an object consisting of key-value pairs. Don't see anything in the documentation about this, though.

Comment: Dear Google, please index this: "mass assignment Ember.js"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is actually a function for this: `setProperties`. You can use it like this:

```
obj.setProperties({prop1: value1, prop2: value2})
```

`obj` should be instance of `Ember.Object`.

Comment: This works great, but the side-effect issue that I'm having is that I have an observable that observes three properties, and even if I only do one mass call like this, it fires off three times if all of the properties are called.

Comment: @JohnCho Perhaps my anwser here could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13317170/373254

Comment: Amazing. I'm going to have to try this out. It's almost a good thing that my project got put on hold.

Comment: I was looking for it for some time... 
Thanks for clean explanation. It did the charm for me.

Comment: @ouren is the something like Ember.setProperties(obj, {prop:value}) ? so that it will work on all objects and not only ember objects ?

Answer (score 29):

As @oruen points out [in his correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758435/614844), you are describing setProperties(...).

One potential issue to be aware of is that according to the JS spec the order of properties on an object is indeterminate. (See [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)).

If you don't care about order, or are confident that the JS implementations you are targeting will respect your order, setProperties should work for you.

When setting multiple properties, you should consider using **Ember.beginPropertyChanges()** and **Ember.endPropertyChanges()**. The former suspends the observer triggers and the latter restores it and flushes. This approach can improve performance. setProperties does this for you.

Also notable is **Ember.changeProperties**, which accepts a callback and calls Ember.beginPropertyChanges, then your callback, and then Ember.endPropertyChanges, even if your callback raised an exception. Example usage:

```
Ember.changeProperties(function() {
  obj1.set('foo', mayBlowUpWhenSet);
  obj2.set('bar', baz);
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Beautiful. I needed to do a rollback, but it kept triggering some methods that were observing the properties before all of the properties could be reset. Thus causing havoc in my code. This Ember.changeProperties was the key to getting everything set to null that I needed and also doing a model.rollback().