# Ember.js: mass-assign attributes while notifying observers

Tags: ember.js

In Ember.js, I'm creating a user object like so, populating it from a JSON API:

```
user = App.User.create({screenName: screenName});
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data) {
    user.reopen(data);
  }
});
return user;
```

Here, `user.reopen(data)` mass-assigns the JSON response onto the user object.

But now observers are not triggered.

Is there a simple way to mass-update attributes while also triggering observers, without resorting to recursive looping?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EmberJS Set Multiple Properties At Once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752805/emberjs-set-multiple-properties-at-once)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `setProperties()`?