# Ember multiple property changes but want to trigger single event

Tags: properties, ember.js

I have a ArrayController for date picker with properties **to** and **from**. Now when user selects a new date range from the UI both **to** and **from** value changes.

So a function which observers on **to** and **from** is trigger twice for a single change in date range.

I want to trigger the function only one every date range change. Any suggestions how to do that with ember

```
    app = Ember.Application.create();

    app.Time = Ember.ArrayController.create({

        to: null,
        from: null,
        rootElement: "#time",

        debug1: function() {
            this.set('to', 1);
            this.set('from', 2);
        },

        debug2: function() {
            this.setProperties( {
                'to': 3,
                'from': 4
            });
        },

        debug3: function() {
            this.beginPropertyChanges();
            this.set('to', 5);
            this.set('from', 6);
            this.endPropertyChanges();
        },

        search: function() {
            alert('called');
        }.observes('to', 'from')
    });
```

[View in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zf2q3/)

Comment: what about observing only to or from ? as the two are changing when the user select a nex date, relying on only one of two could work no ?

Comment: well there are also other ways to change the to and from also. So the observer has to be on both

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you can introduce a computed property on `from` and `to`, and then plug the observer on this property. As CPs are cached by default, I think the observer will be triggered only once.

```
date: function(){
 // return the computed date
}.property('from', 'to')

dateDidChange: function(){

}.observes('date')
```

**EDIT** Thanks to your fiddle, it seems to work using setProperties, or begin/end propertyChanges http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/zf2q3/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap observer in a `Em.run.once`

```
_dateDidChange: function(){
  Ember.run.once(this, 'dateDidChange');
}.observes('from', 'to'),

dateDidChange: function() {
  // should be called only once
}
```

Comment: @AnkurAgarwal Hum, I think this is better what I did. In fact, I have asked for Ember.js contributors to have a look at this. That's why he suggested an other workaround.

Comment: Ankur, can you extrapolate? We are thinking about make observers async, so you will not have to wrap it, it will juste work.

Comment: @Tchak If I use this way, it will work. But being the publisher subscriber paradigm, Lets say if anyone outside of this object want to  observes the changes them it has to explicitly declared in here. This is a nightmare because sometime external observers exist and sometime they dont.

In first answer by sly7_7, external observers can easily observe without them being explicitly declared and no extra code or handling.