# Sorting select option with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, select

I used this code and now the numbers 1-9 with zeros are last after 31. Example "28, 29, 30, 31, 01, 02,". what i want is to have it the regular way 01, 02, 03...09, 10, 11. how would i do this?

```
var everyDay = {};
for (im;im<=31;im++){
     t = (im < 10 ? '0' : '') + im
     everyDay[t] = (im < 10 ? '0' : '') + im;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the object properties are in lexicographical order (`aa`,`ac`,`...`,`az`). Have you tried an array instead?

```
var everyDay = [];
for (var im = 1; im <= 31; im++){
     everyDay.push((im < 10 ? '0' : '') + im);
}
```

However, it's hard to tell since you don't show how you use `everyDay`.

Comment: There is no telling in which way object properties are ordered. Don't build programs that rely on a particular order. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop

Answer (score 0):

everyDay is a hash, which is not sorted by key. You will need to put the values in an array instead. Try this:

```
var days = []
for (im;im<=31;im++){
    t = (im < 10 ? '0' : '') + im
    days.push();
}
```