# JS object key sequence

Tags: javascript

Does javascript guarantees that the sequence of keys of an object gets preserved even if the new value is assigned to a key?

For example, if i have the following object

```
var Object = {
    keyX: value1,
    keyB: value2,
    keyZ: value3
}
```

If i iterate through keys using `for .. in`, I get the proper sequence i.e. `keyX, keyB, keyZ`. and if I change the value of `keyB`, I am still getting the same sequence in iteration.

My question is, will the sequence remains the same always, or it might change in any case?

Comment: I don't think you should rely on the order of the properties in an object.

Comment: The sequence could change at any time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's quite clearly said in the doc ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)):

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an
>   arbitrary order.

And [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues) of documentation gives more comprehensive explanation to this:

> Although ECMAScript makes iteration order of objects
>   implementation-dependent, it may appear that all major browsers
>   support an iteration order based on the earliest added property coming
>   first (at least for properties not on the prototype). However, in the
>   case of Internet Explorer, when one uses delete on a property, some
>   confusing behavior results, preventing other browsers from using
>   simple objects like object literals as ordered associative arrays.
>
> In Explorer, while the property value is indeed set to undefined, if
>   one later adds back a property with the same name, the property will
>   be iterated in its old position--not at the end of the iteration
>   sequence as one might expect after having deleted the property and
>   then added it back.