# Inserting property in JSON object at a specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

I would like to know how I can insert a JSON object property at a specific position?
Let's assume this Javascript object:

```
var data = {
  0: 'lorem',
  1: 'dolor sit',
  2: 'consectetuer'
}
```

I have an ID and a string, like:

```
var id = 6;
var str = 'adipiscing';
```

Now, I would like to insert the `id` between `0` and `1` (for example) and it should be like:

```
data = {
  0: 'lorem',
  6: 'adipiscing',
  1: 'dolor sit',
  2: 'consectetuer'
}
```

**How can I do this?**
Is there any jQuery solution for this?

Comment: I don't think the ECMAScript spec says that object properties must keep any order.

Comment: You can't.  JavaScript's object properties do not have a deterministic order.

Comment: If you need deterministic order of numeric indices, you ought to be using an `Array` `[]` instead.

Comment: Why do you want to so this? to access the string, you'd have to use `data[i]`, where `i` is your id. The order doesn't matter at all, there.

Comment: I think if you NEED the have an object's properties in specific order then there might be a flaw in your design.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/280861/13508

Answer (score 9):

To specify an order in which elements of an object are placed, you'll need to use an array of objects, like this:

```
data = [
    {0: 'lorem'},
    {1: 'dolor sit'},
    {2: 'consectetuer'}
]
```

You can then push a element to a certain position in the array:

```
// Push {6: 'adipiscing'} to position 1
data.splice(1, 0, {6: 'adipiscing'})

// Result:
data = [
    {0: 'lorem'},
    {6: 'adipiscing'},
    {1: 'dolor sit'},
    {2: 'consectetuer'}
]
// Access it:
data[0][0] //"lorem"
```

However, this will render the indices you've specified (`{0:`) pretty much useless.

Comment: The problem is that here you used an array instead of the object

Comment: The problem is that objects in JavaScript don't support ordered iteration, the OP's data structure is weird, and this question is from ***2012***. It's hella' old!