# How to retrieve last entered object from a JSON File?

Tags: json

I have a JSON file with these values :

```
{ 
  id:
  name:
  lastName:
  Info:[ 
    {
      info1:
      info2:
      info3: 
    },
    { 
      info1:
      info2:
      info3:
    }
  ]
}
```

So, Info object has two lists.
I want to be able to access the last one.
data.info[0] is for the first object. How do I access the last one ?
(var data holds the JSON results).
In my Entity I have a Client entity that has a one to many mapping with InfoData,as a list :
Like this :

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference  
    private List<InfoData> info= new ArrayList<InfoData>();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get last element of a json object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148065/get-last-element-of-a-json-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
    var length = data.Info.length; // number of objects in the array
    var requiredObject = {};

    requiredObject = data.Info[length-1]; //get the last object
    console.log(requiredObject);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, but I answered the question first, please tick my answer and upvote it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
var obj = {
name: "test",
Info: [{
       info1: "a",
       info2: "b"
      },{
       info1: "a",
       info2: "b"
       }]
      }

       var lastObject = obj.Info[obj.Info.length - 1];
```

Comment: @JenPenlkjk if it answers the question, please indicate it as the accepted answer and vote up. Thank you!