# getting last element in JSON not working

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to take the last element in a `JSON`. I know order is not preserved, but the keys are `unix` timestamps so I can just sort. I am working from this question:

[get last element of a json object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148065/get-last-element-of-a-json-object-in-javascript)

But I get nothing logged to the console and no errors.

my code:

```
var mydata = {"1509937402379":"7348.01","1509937412486":"7348.01","1509937422253":"7348.01","1509937426286":"7348.01","1509937430066":"7345.54"}

console.log(mydata[Object.keys(obj).sort().pop()]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmb5sd1m/1/

Comment: Just a side note, order actually is preserved in ES6.

Comment: `console.log(mydata[Object.keys(mydata).sort().pop()]);`

Comment: @jhpratt the order of object is not preserved consistently. Namely `Object.keys` does not preserve the order. More at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/1043231

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed.. .You require to use Object.keys(mydata).

```
var mydata = {"1509937402379":"7348.01","1509937412486":"7348.01","1509937422253":"7348.01","1509937426286":"7348.01","1509937430066":"7345.54"}
```

Review same fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lmb5sd1m/1/