# Underscore forEach index?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object that contains the follow structure

```
{
Apples: Array[1],
Mangos: Array[2],
Oranges: Array[5],
Bananas: Array[11]
}
```

These values are extracted using a

```
_.forEach(contents, function(values, key) {

}
```

Where the `key = apples` and the `values` would be the array. I am wondering how I can get the current index within this `foreach` loop ?

i.e. so I get `1,2,3,4` ? There may not be a way to do this other than to push them to an array ?

Comment: "Apples" ≠ "apples"; 1,2,3,4 ≠ 0,1,2,3;

Comment: You should notice that objects are an unordered collection of properties.

Comment: Since it is a hash object, I don't think it preserves the order of keys

Comment: thanks for the responses - i think the easiest way is just to push the key into an array and keep track of it there due the inability to keep track ?

Comment: the position within the object is not useful or meaningful.  why do you think you want it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that I completely got your question, but if you are looking for the index of the item currently enumerated here is a way using the "_forEach" equivalent

```
var test = {"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}
var index = 0;
for (key in test){ alert(key +"is at "+index+" position"); index++;}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be (index++)?

Comment: yes sorry =), also as you mentioned, there is no logical order convention for the keys (only arrays are doing so)

Comment: Even though it is not part of the standard it looks like most browsers share a common behaviour according this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

```
_.each(myArray,function(eachItem,index){
       console.log("item: "+ eachItem + "at index " + index);
    }
```

Example:

```
var myArr = [
Apples: "One",
Mangos: "Two",
Oranges: "Three",
Bananas: "Four"
]

_.each(myArr,function(eachItem,index){
       console.log("item: "+ eachItem + "at index " + index);
    }
```

**Output:**

item:One at index 0

item:Two at index 1

item:Three at index 2

item:Four at index 3

**Reference:**
[Underscore JS Reference Link](http://underscorejs.org/#each)