# Accessing object properties with index gives undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, properties

Below is an a function that contains of an object, and I want to be able to access a specific body within the object with the use of an argument, that is with an index.

The problem is that when I try to access a property this way I get

> undefined

when console logs it. What am I doing wrong?

```
moveLeftBtn.on('click', function(nr){
    var theBody = {
        bodies: {
            a: 'foo1',
            b: 'foo2',
            c: 'foo3'
        }
    };

    var newBody = theBody.bodies[1];    // temporarily hardcoded value instead of argument
    console.log(newBody);    // <-- undefined, why?

    return newBody;
});
```

**EDIT**

If I console log `theBody.bodies` I can see it's value (`Object {a: Array[5], b: Array[5], c: Array[5]}`), but when I try to access it's properties with `[1]` I get

> undefined

(even though the properties contains of strings).

Comment: `theBody.bodies[nr]` is correct. This is called "bracket notation". See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json. Your edited code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/q9ECP/. Note that bracket notation is not a special notation for arrays, it's how property access works in general. **If** identifiers were allowed to start with a digit, you could access an array with `arr.1` instead of `arr[1]`. The same way you can access plain objects either with `obj.foo` or `obj['foo']`.

Comment: Relevant section in the specification: http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1.

Comment: if you want the items to be `null`, remove quotes around `'null'` values

Comment: there is a superfluous comma after `'test3'`

Comment: @Igor: Yes, I know. Just put something in there but I changed it now.

Comment: @Igor: Fixed the comma btw, thx.

Comment: @holyredbeard - ok, now there is a missing semicolon after `theBody` assignment

Comment: If you see `(Object {a: Array[5], b: Array[5], c: Array[5]})`, then the properties of `theBody.bodies'` are `a`, `b`, `c`, not `1`, `2`, `3`. Of course `theBody.bodies[1]` will show `undefined` then. It should be `theBody.bodies['a']`. Do you want to access a property by index instead by name? That's not possible (at least not directly).

Comment: The representation of your data in your question doesn't seem to match what you actually have.

Comment: So, what's your actual question, now that you changed the object? Do you really want to access the object with an index? Please clarify.

Comment: @FelixKling: Convert your comment to an answer because you got the solution :)

Comment: TBH, I'd rather close this as "too localized".

Answer (score 1):

The only issue that I see with your code is that you aren't returning anything.  Change . . .

```
var newBody = theBody.bodies[nr];
```

. . . to . . .

```
return theBody.bodies[nr];
```

. . . and you should be good to go.

**Edit:** Oh, you're also missing the `;` after you define `theBody`.

Comment: Thanks! Thing is that I get undefined if doing that. Very strange!

Comment: What value are you passing in?  I've tested it locally (after adding in the return statement, above) and calling the function like this: `AccessBody(1);` is returning the text in the object (tested in IE7 and Firefox).

Comment: Also missing a colon after defining `theBody` . . . updated answer.

Comment: *"Oh, you're also missing the `;` after you define `theBody`."* Luckily semicolons are optional ;) The problem is not with the syntax, it's with the data structure.

Comment: I updated my questions to the exact function i'm trying with (now hardcoded value, [1], instead of argument). Same thing. :/

Comment: Yeah, what @FelixKling said (up in the question comments) . . . now that you've changed the keys to letters, you have to call them with the strings "a", "b", and "c".

Answer (score 1):

`theBody.bodies` is an object with three properties named `a`, `b`, and `c`. You did not give it any property named `1`. That's why the value of `theBody.bodies[1]` is `undefined`. If you reference `theBody.bodies['b']` you will find one of the properties you expect, with a value of `'foo1'`.

It sounds like you just need to read up on JavaScript arrays and objects and how they work. Don't make any assumptions based on things like "associative arrays" you may have used in other languages. JavaScript is a language of its own with its own ways of doing things, so you just need to learn those.

Answer (score 0):

`theBody.bodies` is not an array but a plain object. Normally you cannot access fields of plain object with numeric indices.

But you can walkaround it by defining `theBody.bodies` object like that:

```
var theBody = {
    bodies: {
        '0': 'foo1',
        '1': 'foo2',
        '2': 'foo3'
    }
}
```

With `bodies` defined in such way there will be `theBody.bodies[1] === 'foo2'`.

If you by any reasons cannot change `bodies` than you may process it and create another object which fields you can access with numeric index - like that:

```
var newBodies = [], i = 0, j;
for (j in theBody.bodies) {
    newBodies.push(theBody.bodies[j]);
}
```

In case you `theBody.bodies` in not always plain object (for example instance of some type) than instead of `for` loop it should be iterated with `$.each` or `for` loop should be extended with `hasOwnProperty` check.

Comment: *"Normally you cannot access fields of plain object with numeric indices."* Well, it's no different for arrays (since arrays are just objects as well). You can only access properties that exist. The *property name* can be any arbitrary character sequence though. In case of arrays, numerical property names are treated in a special way.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing works great on Firefox, but I don's know about other browsers. You will have to add more logic for index checking. You should not access objects by an index anyway, because the order of the properties may change and you should treat them as a map or a set as opposed to an indexed list.

I attached a `getByIndex()` function on all objects for this example. You can create your own object and attach the function to it.

Here is a JSFiddle I made that works for what you need it to do: http://jsfiddle.net/zKrbr/4/

```js
Object.prototype.getByIndex = function (property, index) {
    var n = 0;
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        for (var prop in this[property]) {
            if (n == index) {
                console.log('Found Match: '+prop+': '+this[property][prop]);
                return this[property][prop];
            } else {
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

$('#moveLeft').on('click', function (nr) {
    var theBody = {
        bodies: {
            a: 'foo1',
            b: 'foo2',
            c: 'foo3'
        }
    };
    var index = parseInt($('#input').val());
    var currIndex = !isNaN(index) ? index : 0;
    var newBody = theBody.getByIndex('bodies', currIndex);
    $('#output').val(newBody);
});
```

```html
<strong>Index:<strong>
<input type="text" id="input" size="3"/>
<input type="button" id="moveLeft" value="Move Left" />
<input type="text" id="output" />
```

Comment: Your `Object.prototype.getByIndex` function won't work reliably, because properties are not sorted. The order in which the properties are iterated over can be different from browser to browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/280713/218196.

Comment: I understand, as I have stated: `you should treat them as a map or a set as opposed to an indexed list`. I was just throwing out a suggestion.

Comment: Ok. I wouldn't suggest something like that though. It's just too unreliable.