# Acessing multi-dimensional arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

JavaScript question: I want to confirm the correctness of a method for accessing elements in a 2-D array. In a JS code I found for the Knapsack problem, a 2-D array is initialized by

```
var data= [ {name:'map',     weight=9,   value:150, pieces:1},
        {name:'compass', weight:13,  value:35,  pieces:1},
        {name:'water',   weight:153, value:200, pieces:2} ];
```

Later in the code an index j is incremented and the code references the array by

```
data[j].name
data[j].weight
data[j].value
data[j].pieces
```

I assume that this is the same as referencing the array using just indices as

```
data[j][1]
data[j][2]
```

etc.

Is this correct? I would very much like to use the strings as indices rather then the indices for convenience.

I have looked in Crockford's book (JS: The Good Parts) and Sam's JS in 24 Hours, but they are not clear. I have also looked online but only got more confused. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Array vs object. Not the same.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the object with `data[j][1]`? It won't work.

Comment: use the javascript console to run and check your js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing object properties with index gives undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095566/accessing-object-properties-with-index-gives-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate an array by using indexes, and then objects through dot notation like so:

```
data[0].name returns "map";
data[1].name returns "compass";
```

you cannot access object properties by indexes because objects are not array's and do not have indexes, they have properties, so you have to access them by property name.

Comment: However, numbers can be property names too. If you have an object like `var foo = {1: 42};` then the property has to be accessed with `foo[1]`. In fact, arrays are nothing else but objects, but which treat properties with numeric names in a special way.

Answer (score 0):

The elements inside your example array are objects, but not arrays, so I'd probably call that a 1-D array of objects (unless you like to think of objects as associative arrays).

Anyways, `data[j][1]` won't work with your example, because none of the `data` elements can be indexed by `1`. Instead, use something like `data[j].name` or `data[j]['name']`.

Here's what I would personally call a 2-D array, where `data[j][1]` would be meaningful:

```
var data = [ [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'] ];
```

...and another example where `data[j][1]` would work using an array of (non-array) objects:

```
var data = [ { 1: 'one' }, { 1 : 'uno' } ];
```