# Converting array of Javascript objects to a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript object and when I JSON.stringify it, it looks like following

```
[
    {
        "item_id": null,
        "parent_id": "none",
        "depth": 0,
        "left": "1",
        "right": 4
    },
    {
        "item_id": "1",
        "parent_id": null,
        "depth": 1,
        "left": 2,
        "right": 3
    }
]
```

I want to convert it to a multi-dimensional array which looks like the following

```
item[0][0] = item_id
item[0][1] = parent_id
item[0][2] = depth
item[0][3] = left
item[0][4] = right

item[1][0] = item_id
item[1][1] = parent_id
item[1][2] = depth
item[1][3] = left
item[1][4] = right
```

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Edit : Got it working with the help of all :) Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Please post your code so far so we can help.

Comment: Why do u want an array ?

Comment: do you want the array to have they keys or the corresponding values

Comment: @Arun - I want the corresponding values

Comment: @DarkBee - I have a function which accepts an array, which I want to pass these data into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well lets take the initial object (array) prior to the `stringify`. With this we can loop each item. Then we can create a new array for each property. Something like this:

```
var myObject = X;//this is your original object
var newArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++){
   var item = myObject[i];
   var subArray = [];
   subArray.push(item["item_id"]);
   subArray.push(item["parent_id"]);
   subArray.push(item["depth"]);
   subArray.push(item["left"]);
   subArray.push(item["right"]);
   newArray.push(subArray);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/WtPtr/) (check the console for the result)

**NOTE**: I purposefully avoided using a `for in` loop due to the rumours I always hear about the reliability of order. Of course, if you trust it then it's your call, but I prefer to play on the safe side. [You can read some other opinions of this matter here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop).

---

If you want to increase the performance, you could create an array directly from the values, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
    var item = myObject[i];
    var subArray = [item["item_id"], item["parent_id"], item["depth"], item["left"], item["right"]];
    newArray.push(subArray);
}
```

This is approximately twice as fast performance wise, [here is the proof](http://jsperf.com/convert-objects-to-arrays)

Comment: How about replacing lots of those lines with: 
`newArray.push(["item_id", "parent_id", "depth", "left", "right"].reduce(function(p, c) { return p.concat(item[c]); }, []));`

Comment: @Amberlamps: No thanks, I like to make sure my answers can be understood by the OP ;-)

Comment: @Amberlamps: Also, yours appears slower than mine. I also did a third option which is faster than both. [Here are the results](http://jsperf.com/convert-objects-to-arrays)

Comment: @musefan: Yeah, performance-wise `reduce` seem to suck. An iterative solution seems always the best way to me. What is your third option?

Comment: @Amberlamps: The third option was in my performance test link, but I have updated my answer to include it anyway

Comment: @musefan: This is nice! But now you can just put the array into the push function and omit the `subArray` variable after all.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Indeed, I tested that too, but the performance was too close to be worth the readability hit. Infact, the first test I run it had slightly worse performance anyway, and the second test it was slightly better

Answer (score 1):

Your "object" is actually an Array.

```
var item = [];
for (var i=0; i<yourArray.length; i++) {
   var subArray = [];
   var obj = yourArray[i];
   for (var j in obj) {
      subArray.push(j);
   }
   item.push(subArray);
}
```

Comment: You should extract field value, not field name.

Comment: No, the question asks for field name.

Comment: Actually the question is not really clear about that, but come on, it is kind of obvious that OP meant values not keys.

Comment: @JoeBeuckman: It doesn't ask for field name. The example shows the field name as a variable. Which to me indicates they want the value of that field. Using field names would make no sense anyway

Answer (score 0):

map your array elements by iterating over the fields of each of the objects

```
var item = yourarray.map(function (o) { 
  var s =[];
  for (var f in o) { 
    s.push(o[f]);
  }
  return s; 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

With recursion, for not limited dimensions of the **data** object:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Gqp2/1/)

```
 function isArray($obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call($obj) === '[object Array]';
}

function subObject(data) {


    if(isArray(data)){
        return (subArray(data));
    }

    var result = [];
    for (var i in data) {
        var item = data[i];
        if (item === null) { // null type is ojbect ..!
            result.push(item);
        } else if (isArray(item)) {
            result.push(subArray(item));
        } else if (typeof item === 'object') {
            result.push(subObject(item));
        } else {
            result.push(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function subArray(data) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i]; 
        if (item === null) { // null type is ojbect ..!
            result.push(item);
        } else if (isArray(item)) {
            result.push(subArray(item));
        } else if (typeof item === 'object') {
            result.push(subObject(item));
        } else {
            result.push(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var r = subObject(data);
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Recursion is a little too much for this problem. OP is not saying anything about more dimensions. Also, the type of an array is "object"!

Comment: this doesn't actually work. If throws a `null` reference error on one of the recursive calls

Comment: Do not use `for ... in` on arrays. To check whether a variable is an array or not use `Object.prototype.toString.call(item) === '[object Array]'`

Comment: OK example works properly now. It is probably way more complex then the OP needs but it is good for reference. Thanks to @Amberlamps for the input.