# How to arrange option value using with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my script:

```
    var myobject = {
    'Any' : 'Any',
    '1' : 'One',
    '2' : 'Two',
    '3' : 'Three',
    '4' : 'Four',
    '5' : 'Five'
};

var select = document.getElementById("TypeList1");
for(index in myobject) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(myobject[index], index);
}
```

I am getting dropdown like this:

```
<select id="TypeList1" class="custom1 interactive1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="Any">Any</option>
</select>
```

But I want to generate like this way:

```
<select id="TypeList1" class="custom1 interactive1">
  <option value="Any">Any</option>  
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a74FN/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're relying on an associative (i.e. non-indexed) structure (object) to output according to index. Your `index` variable actually holds the named key of the property, not its index.

Instead, use an array, which IS indexed. Each entry in the array is a sub-array containing the value and the text for the option.

```
var arr = [
    ['Any', 'Any'],
    ['1', 'One'],
    ['2', 'Two'],
    ['3', 'Three'],
    ['4', 'Four'],
    ['5', 'Five']
];

var select = document.getElementById("TypeList1");
for (var i=0, len = arr.length; i<len; i++)
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(arr[i][1], arr[i][0]);
```

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop[link]

Comment: Thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add this line just after the for loop :

```
jQuery('option:last').insertBefore('option:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery You can do this as below.

**Change your object as below,**

```
var myobject = {
    '1' : 'One',
    '2' : 'Two',
    '3' : 'Three',
    '4' : 'Four',
    '5' : 'Five'
};
$("<option></option>", 
     {value: "Any", text: "Any"})
    .appendTo('#TypeList1');

$.each(myobject , function(i , v){
  $("<option></option>", 
     {value: i, text: v})
    .appendTo('#TypeList1');
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a74FN/1/)