# Object fields sequence

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object written in javascript code as below:

```
var rtnStr = {"000":"area000","020":"area020","030":"area030",
              "040":"area040","047":"area047","049":"area049",
              "050":"area050","060":"area060","070":"area070",
              "100":"area100", "900":"area900"};

for (var key in rtnStr) {
  document.write('rtnStr[' + key + ']= ' + rtnStr[key] + '<br />');
}
```

then I run the code in browser, I got the result:

```
rtnStr[100]= area100
rtnStr[900]= area900
rtnStr[000]= area000
rtnStr[020]= area020
rtnStr[030]= area030
rtnStr[040]= area040
rtnStr[047]= area047
rtnStr[049]= area049
rtnStr[050]= area050
rtnStr[060]= area060
rtnStr[070]= area070
```

the object fields(keys) sequence is not the same as I have declare, How can I got the result as below?

```
rtnStr[000]= area000
rtnStr[020]= area020
rtnStr[030]= area030
rtnStr[040]= area040
rtnStr[047]= area047
rtnStr[049]= area049
rtnStr[050]= area050
rtnStr[060]= area060
rtnStr[070]= area070
rtnStr[100]= area100
rtnStr[900]= area900
```

Comment: That's JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: its because obects have no defined order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

Comment: Object properties are unordered.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects are unordered.

If you want to output their properties in a sorted order then:

1. Create an array
2. Loop over the object, pushing the property names into the array
3. Sort the array
4. Loop over the array (and use the values to access the original object).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var rtnStr = {"000":"area000","020":"area020","030":"area030",
              "040":"area040","047":"area047","049":"area049",
              "050":"area050","060":"area060","070":"area070",
              "100":"area100", "900":"area900"};

  array_ = [];

  for (var key in rtnStr) {
    array_.push(key)
  }

  array_.sort();


  for (var key in array_) {
    document.write('rtnStr[' + key + ']= ' + rtnStr[key] + '<br />');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Quentin, the order of the properties in JavaScript objects is undefined. The spec doesn't even mention if the properties will be returned in the same order by different `for..in`s.

What you can do is get the keys in an array and sort them:

```
var rtnStr = {"000":"area000","020":"area020","030":"area030",
              "040":"area040","047":"area047","049":"area049",
              "050":"area050","060":"area060","070":"area070",
              "100":"area100", "900":"area900"};

var keys = Object.keys(rtnStr).sort().forEach(function(key){
  document.write('rtnStr[' + key + ']= ' + rtnStr[key] + '<br />');
});
```

MDN has a page for [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) where you can find the browsers it works on and a polyfill for those it doesn't.

One thing to note is that your initial version of the code iterates over inherited properties as well. That is generally considered to be unsafe and `Object.keys` doesn't exhibit that behavior.