# JSON.parse() returns alphabetical order

Tags: json

I'm parsing my string value to json object.
while doing this it returns the json object with different order.

```
var l = '{"creationType":"ITEMCLASSES","maxLevelNo":"4","selectbox1":"11001","textbox11":"KRAFT PAPER","hidden11":"11001","textbox12":"FG2","hidden12":"11051","textbox13":"HMC2","hidden13":"11045","textbox14":"2","textbox15":"LS2","hidden15":"11048","textbox16":"123","hidden16":"11015","selectbox2":"11002","textbox21":"kraft ","hidden21":"11057","selectbox3":"11003","textbox31":"40 BF","hidden31":"11004","textbox32":"Natural Color","hidden32":"11006","textbox33":"2","textbox41":"140 GSM","hidden41":"11008"}';       
var o = JSON.parse(l);
alert(0);
```

resultant object is ordered based on the name.
how to avoid this situation?
kindly give your suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

Comment: Object order is not guaranteed. There is more information in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "1" is already a JSON object. This means that feeding it into the JSON.parse function is both redundant and unnescesarry. The JSON.parse(); function is primarily used when converting strings to JSON objects.

```
var l = {"creationType":"ITEMCLASSES","maxLevelNo":"4","selectbox1":"11001","textbox11":"KRAFT PAPER","hidden11":"11001","textbox12":"FG2","hidden12":"11051","textbox13":"HMC2","hidden13":"11045","textbox14":"2","textbox15":"LS2","hidden15":"11048","textbox16":"123","hidden16":"11015","selectbox2":"11002","textbox21":"kraft ","hidden21":"11057","selectbox3":"11003","textbox31":"40 BF","hidden31":"11004","textbox32":"Natural Color","hidden32":"11006","textbox33":"2","textbox41":"140 GSM","hidden41":"11008"};
alert(1);
```

Just skip the second line and manipulate your "1" variable directly.

Comment: actually var l contains string value so that i externally parse to json object.

Comment: sure - in that case I would recommend using XML or an array if you want to maintain the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

As described by [www.json.org](http://www.json.org)

> In JSON, they take on these forms:
>
> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

Use an array if you want to maintain the order.