# How read json file with order garantee in javascript (nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

It is needed to read json file and write it back with uppedned changes into the end of file. For example:

```
//original
{"k1": "v1", "k4": "v4"}
```

do some magic and get:

```
//output
{"k1": "v1", "k4": "v4", "k2": "v2"}
```

The big problem here is `JSON.stringify()` / `JSON.parse()` call does not garantee en order of json jey during `parse` / `stringify` - so json is read into unordered map and written into unordered map again.

Can this be with javascript???

Comment: Is that really an issue since you can still access your member with `myObj.k1`, `myObj.k4`, `myObj.k2` no matter what their order is ?

Comment: Related to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006162/keep-order-of-objects-inside-a-json-string-after-they-are-parsed"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`reviver` argument](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/json/parse) of `JSON.parse` to remember keys order and then use it to reestablish the order using the [`replacer` argument](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/json/stringify) of `JSON.stringify`:

```js
let src = '{"y":1,"z":2,"x":3}'
let keysOrder = []
JSON.parse(src, (key, value) => {keysOrder.push(key); return value})
let res = JSON.stringify({z: 1, y: 2, x: 3}, keysOrder)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maps/Objects attributes in Javascript are unordered. So direct answer is : you can't.

Now you can try to mitigate this by using an array :

```
[{"k1": "v1"}, {"k2": "v2"}, etc...]
```

You can create and sort this array before the `stringify`, and re-assemble the object after the `parse`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question explicitly asks for order **after** being serialized.

Comment: I quite don't understand your comment, if you serialize an array and parse it, the order will be kept.

Comment: That is correct. But its not about order in arrays, but order of **serialized** keys of an object.

Comment: OP is also talking about the `parse` function and not only about the serialize part, which once parsed, no order will be guaranteed. If it's just about the serialized string output, your answer is correct.

Comment: You are right. This is also solvable when using `JSON.parse` (see my answer)