# How to refer to the object property if the property name can be any

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have, for example, the following array of objects:

```
data = [{id:name1, num1:12, num2:8},
        {id:name2, num1:5, num2:13},
        {id:name3, num1:21, num2:4}];
```

I am wondering, how can I refer only to property "num1" of all objects or "num2", considering, that I don't know the exact name of the property.
So if I want to find the Sum of all num2 I cannot do it simply writing the following piece of code:

```
data.forEach(function(obj) {
Sum += obj.num2;
};
```

Cause "num2" may not be called "num2" but any other name, depending on the generated report (data is taken from the Microstrategy reporting system). And it is inconvenient to change the code every time just to meet the property name.

Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: So how would identify the "column" to sum? By position?

Comment: Why don't you put all the numbers in an array inside the object instead of the current structure? Example: `data = [{id: 'x', num: [12, 8]}];`

Comment: Will the custom name for the "num2" key always be placed as the 3rd key in every object?

Comment: Use `object[variable_with_prop_name]`. BTW `object.property` is just a shortcut to `object["property"]`.

Comment: Can you clarify which column you want to sum up

Comment: @OliverQueen, because I get the data from the report in csv format first, and in that case it will have every value in the row in separate column, with own property name :/

Comment: @JonathanNielsen, yes, it will be always placed as the 3rd key in every object.

Comment: @user7, I want to be able to sum up the 2nd and 3rd columns with numeric values. To get Sum_num1 and Sum_num2, for example.

Comment: I guess unless you have the values in an array, you cannot do it as in javascript, properties order in an object cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: See: [Elements order in a “for (… in …)” loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)  "Currently all major browsers loop over the properties of an object in the order in which they were defined."

Comment: @user7, well, I did it, so it's possible :) Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, but this is what I would do to create a Sum object from the original

```
data = [{
  id: 'name1',
  num1: 12,
  num2: 8
}, {
  id: 'name2',
  num1: 5,
  num2: 13
}, {
  id: 'name3',
  num1: 21,
  num2: 4
}];

var Sum = {};
data.forEach(function(obj) {

  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach(function(k) {
  if( i )
    if (Sum.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      Sum[k] += obj[k];
    } else {
      Sum[k] = obj[k];
    }
  })
})

console.log(Sum);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d6vttp9v/

Note: this also sums the string field, so its kind of nonsense, but you could easily specify an array of column to exclude (exercise for the reader).

So this answer doesn't get you exactly what you want (I'm not sure exactly what you want), but hopefully its a good step in right direction.

Answer (score -2):

You can access an objects properties like so:

```
var x = { someProp1: 'x', someProp2: 'y' };
for(prop in x) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

Heres a handy [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

If this question is more generally about schema changes in JSON objects and whats the best approach to that, heres an angle I use.

for example the ajax call `getPeople`

```
myApp.ajaxSchemas.getPeople = {
  NAME: 'Name',
  AGE: 'Age'
};
```

I would then refer to the schema in my code:

```
someObject[myApp.ajaxSchemas.getPeople.NAME];
```

This means that when theres a schema change it is managed in one place, the `myApp.ajaxSchemas.getPeople` definition.

I hope this helps.

Rhys

Comment: Why have I been downvoted?

Comment: have no idea. I cannot vote yet, because have not enough reputation. Thx for answer, I'll try it :)

Comment: Because you didn't understand question.

Comment: I see. I will update my answer

Comment: I also think you were downvoted because `for..in` would be a better loop choice for something like this

Comment: Oliver  I am trying to express that the result of Object.keys is an array

Comment: My answer has been updated

Comment: `Object.prototype.keys` does not exist, have you tested your code before posting it? `Object.keys(x)` is what you're looking for

Comment: Ops, i ment the static `func` `Object.keys()`

Comment: .....? answer updated...