# JavaScript object: Will calls to Object.keys() return the keys in the same order?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };
const keys1 = Object.keys(obj);
const keys2 = Object.keys(obj);
```

Am I guaranteed that the elements of `keys1` will be in the same order as those in `keys2`?

Will `Object.keys()` always return keys in the same order if called on an object which remains unmodified between calls (assuming both calls are performed in the same environment)?

My question is similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/835092) about dictionary behavior in Python.

Comment: Yep, the order is guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: Btw, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41761732/1048572) is the exact equivalent to the python one

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will be in the same order if written in the format as you have mentioned.