# jquery populate select options with json matching same order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following json data:

```
 {
      "324": "Aguacate",
      "196": "Fresa",
      "7875": "Mandarina",
      "197": "Platano",
      "9517": "Uvas"
 }
```

For any reason, when I populate the target select dropdown's options, it returns the options in a different order (by ID):

```
 {
      "196": "Fresa",
      "197": "Platano",
      "324": "Aguacate",
      "7875": "Mandarina",
      "9517": "Uvas"
 }
```

Considering that the script looks like:

```
  $.getJSON("http://path/to/blabla.json", customfunction);

  function customfunction(data) {

        var $select = $('#mymail_data_socio'); 

        // First, empty the select field
        $select.find('option').remove();

        $.each(data,function(key, value) {
              $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
        });

  }
```

Is there any way to return the options in the same order as in my json file? How I should rewrite my script in order to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/280861/3437663

Answer (score 2):

This is a browser specific issue (basically chrome issue), where the browser javascript engine loops through the object properties in order (numeric properties) : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

You can use a prefix and then replace it in the loop as follows:

```js
var obj = {
      "id_324": "Aguacate",
      "id_196": "Fresa",
      "id_7875": "Mandarina",
      "id_197": "Platano",
      "id_9517": "Uvas"
 };
 
 function customfunction(data) {

        var $select = $('#mymail_data_socio'); 

        // First, empty the select field
        $select.find('option').remove();

        $.each(data,function(key, value) {
              $select.append('<option value=' + key.replace('id_', '') + '>' + value + '</option>');
        });

  }
  
  customfunction(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mymail_data_socio"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use `JSONArray` and can be iterated with inner loop (can be quite hectic with more than one iteration) which will give the desired result with the same order specified.

[here is the example with both ways](https://jsfiddle.net/oh33457a/)