# In what order vee-validate works with validator? (Sync and Async)

Tags: validation, vue.js, vee-validate

Beeing new to [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) and [VeeValidate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/) I was wondering in what order  validator functions (rules) associated to a field were validated? (as the doc doesn't really mention it)

I was used to [Angular docs about validator function](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validator-functions) and want to know if *sync* validator are called before *async* ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at **VeeValidate** 2.0.9 source code about validator.js starting [line 649](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/blob/2.0.9/src/core/validator.js#L649) we can note a `_validate` method that will (roughly):

1. Create an `Array` with the field rules using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) then do a [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on it
2. Use the [`_test` method](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/blob/2.0.9/src/core/validator.js#L485) and store the `result` (that is directly the result of the validation or a `Promise`)
3. Stack async (and sync if a [`fastExit`](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/api/directive.html#continues) property is false on this Validator instance) validators (`Promise`) in an array with a `push`
4. Exit if an error occur on a sync validator (with the `fastExit` property)
5. [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the `Array` containing all of the results to return a final result with errors stacked

So quoting MDN about the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method:

> The **Object.keys()** method returns an array of a given object's property **names**, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

And to quote another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop#280861):

> [Quoting John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-in-chrome/):
>
> Currently all major browsers loop over the properties of an object in
>   the order in which they were defined. Chrome does this as well, except
>   for a couple cases. [...] This behavior is explicitly left undefined
>   by the ECMAScript specification. In ECMA-262, section 12.6.4:
>
> > The mechanics of enumerating the properties ... is implementation dependent.
>
> However, specification is quite different from implementation. All modern implementations of ECMAScript iterate through object properties in the order in which they were defined. Because of this the Chrome team has deemed this to be a bug and will be fixing it.

### Conclusion

**The final order will be dependent of the browser implementation of `Object.keys`**, so mostly by the order of definition of the validators but could also be alphabetically!

By default the `fastExit` property is `false` but could be overwritten in the validator options. This option will take the first `false` result from sync validators and return it's errors. If not set **the result will be a compilation of all errors after the verification of every validators.**