# Is it possible to add values from array to object properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is it possible to map values from array to javascript object?

Let's say that we have array like this

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

and an object

```
let someObject = {
SAAB: null,
VOLVO: null,
BMW: null
}
```

And I want to map values from array to object to output it like this:

```
let someObject = {
    SAAB: "Saab",
    VOLVO: "Volvo",
    BMW: "BMW"
    }
```

I tried something along this lines but failed miserably

```
for (let key of Object.entries(someObject)) {
  for (let index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
    key = cars[index];
  }
}
```

Also, I tried this solution but somehow I missed something and it mapped only last value

```
for (var key in someObject) {
  for (var car in cars) {
    someObject[key] = cars[car]
  }
}
console.log(someObject)

{SAAB: "BMW", VOLVO: "BMW", BMW: "BMW"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship is the order you could use `for in` and `shift()`

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

let someObject = {
SAAB: null,
VOLVO: null,
BMW: null
}


for(let p in someObject){
    someObject[p] = cars.shift()
}

console.log(someObject)
```

Order in a `For in` loop is not guaranteed by ECMAScript specification,  but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop), either way order probably is not the best way to relation things.

Comment: True, it's correct. We only need to declare p variable otherwise we get reference error. Like this: `for (let p in someObject) {
  someObject[p] = cars.shift()
}`

Comment: In this case, it's the same, but it's better declare p

Comment: what about not sorted array?

Comment: @аlexdykyі we need some relation. I guess in this case the order, but could be the strings or other thing.

Comment: @Emeeus it's not a answer, please fix your code or remove answer

Comment: @alexdykyi why should I fix my code? I'm saying in certain circumstances this is the solution, just as Gigi answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map even though the relationship between the two objects might not be the order you can something like this:

```
for(let car of cars){
someObject[car.toUpperCase()] = car;
}
```

Which eventually fixes any missing values in the object.
Also you can add a check so that only pre-existing values in the object get their value assigned:

```
for(let car of cars){
if(someObject[car.toUpperCase()])
    someObject[car.toUpperCase()] = car;
}
```