# Does javascript "for x in array" garuntee order?

Tags: javascript

I know that using `for...in` is meant to be for objects, and I also know that `for i=0;i<arr.length;i++` loops work fine, but sometimes I want to use `for..in`s for looping through arrays (I code in both python and js, but my poor brain doesn't want to constantly change my coding style.)

My question is: Is it guarunteed that using `for...in` will give me array objects in order?

PS. My question is specifically for ARRAYS, instead of objects with potential ambiguity in order, so I thought it might be different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

Comment: @Thornkey, there's a `for...of` loop you can use for arrays (and other iterables)

Comment: ik, doesnt seem to work in all browsers though ;-;

Comment: @Trent yeah i was just wondering about arrays specifically :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, property order is not guaranteed, even with array indicies. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) says:

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and are otherwise identical to general object properties. There is no guarantee that `for...in` will return the indexes in any particular order. The `for...in` loop statement will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.

I don't think there are many situations to use `for..in`. If you're working with an array, better to use array methods like `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, and so on.